# How can I stop a recordset being returned by a SQL Server stored procedure if an error is encountered after the SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hoping someone can help. I'm trying to stop a stored procedure from returning a recordset that has been selected, if an error is encountered later in the stored procedure. I've included some pseudo code below to show what I'm doing. Basically, the SELECT [Foo] is returning a recordset if the  or COMMIT actions fail and [Tran1] is rolled back. The client does not support multiple recordsets and the  has to come after the SELECT so I'm looking for a command to place in the CATCH block that effectively cancels the SELECT [Foo] and instead enables me to return the recordset created by SELECT -1 AS [Error_Code]

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION           [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        <Do some Update>

        SELECT          [Foo]
        FROM            [Bar]

        <Do some Insert>

        COMMIT TRANSACTION  [Tran1]
    END TRY


    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    [Tran1]
        SELECT          -1      AS  Error_Code  
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Stuff the results of your `SELECT` in a table variable or temp table and select it only at the end when everything has succeeded. Alternatively, make your client handle this case correctly: an error should mean any results ar ediscarded/not used. For completeness, you cannot retroactively cancel or undo a rowset stream from T-SQL once it has started.

Comment: It's not totally clear but I think you need to SET XACT_ABORT ON

Comment: Adding to @JeroenMostert's comment, results are streamed to the client as the select statement executes. Those results must be consumed before the the client can detect the error returned by the server. Since your client doesn't support multiple result sets, you must ensure the row-returning statement is last one in the batch. More info [here](https://www.dbdelta.com/the-curious-case-of-undetected-sql-exceptions/).